# Écriture du mot 'été'

Tags: étymologie

Pourquoi le mot été (saison) s'écrit comme le participe passé du verbe être. Je pense à l'étymologie

> Wallon, osté ; Berry, sté, asté, sécheresse ; bourguign. étai ; provenç. estat, s. f. ; ital. state, estate ; du latin æstatem, du radical æst qui est dans æstus, chaleur, et dans le grec αἴθειν, brûler, identique avec le sanscrit idh, allumer. ([Littré pour la saison](https://www.littre.org/definition/%C3%A9t%C3%A9)

mais je me demande si ça est l'explication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est une coïncidence que l'on retrouve un peu en italien:

saison: *est**a**te*
participe passé: *st**a**to*

(Le gras marque l'accent tonique.)

L'étymologie n'est donc pas à l'origine de la similitude de ces deux mots.

Le participe passé du verbe être, ***été***, vient du latin vulgaire ***essere*** (latin classique ***esse***) qui vient de l'indo-européen ***es-*** comme le grec ***είναι*** alors que la saison vient du latin ***aestas***, saison chaude, de l'indo-européen ***ai-dh-*** brûler, grec **αἴθω**.

Si les deux mots s'écrivent de la même façon, c'est surtout parce qu'ils se prononçaient et se prononcent encore de la même façon.

Answer (score 3):

L'e accent aigu proviendrait d'un changement général qui aurait pris place après 1100 ; un « et » final ainsi que certains autres groupes  comme « ez » à la fin de certains mots a été transformé en é.

*[été](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9t%C3%A9)*

> Ca 1100 ested (Roland, éd. J. Bédier, 2628 : Ço est en mai, al premer jur d'ested); id. estet (ibid., 3162 : blancs cume flur en estet); ca 1140 esté (G. Gaimar, Hist. des Anglais, éd. A. Bell, 3039)

*[blé](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bl%C3%A9)*

> 1. 1100 blet « céréale dont le grain sert à l'alimentation » (Roland, 980 dans T.-L.); 1160-74 blé (Wace, Rou, III, 5150, ibid.); 1231 blef (Ch. de Morv.-s.-Seille dans Gdf. Compl.);

*[fossé](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foss%C3%A9)*

> Ca 1100 fosset (Roland, éd. Bédier, 2590 : E Mahumet enz un fosset butent);

*[abbé](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abb%C3%A9)*

> Corresp. rom. : a. prov. ábas; n. prov. abát; ital. roum. abate; esp. abad; port. abade; cat. abat. 1100 « supérieur d'une abbaye » (Roland, éd. Bédier, 2955 : Asez i ad evesques et abéz); ca 1130 « id. » (Couronnement de Louis, éd. Langlois, 1762 : Iluec trova et evesques et abes). Empr. au lat. chrét. abbātem (acc. de abbás, d'où la forme ábes) empr. lui-même à l'araméen par l'intermédiaire du grec eccl. α ́ ϐ ϐ α ̃ « père » (en s'adressant à Dieu) », Nouv. Test., passim. Lat. d'abord sous la forme abba, fréquente jusqu'au ixes., de même sens que le gr. (cf. St Jérôme, ds epist. ad Gal. 4, 6 ds Blaise : cum abba pater Hebraeo Syroque dicatur); attest. continues en lat. chrét. et médiév. au sens de « supérieur d'une abbaye ». HIST. − Attesté pour la 1re fois en 1100 (cf. étymol.), abbé est encore empl. dans la lang. contemp. dans son accept. primitive en usage dep. St Benoît.